# Object without code and One Definition Rule

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

Is ODR about "code in the object has to have one definition" since linker will choose one code randomly, so if there is no confusing code, then no problem even the object definition is different?

Examples:

1.cpp

```
struct SA{
    int i;
    float f;   
};
```

2.cpp

```
struct SA{
    long i;
    double f;
    int j;
};
```

(1) Is this considered ODR violated by the standard?
(2) Will this ever have any problem if they are only used locally?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the intention of ODR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030754/what-is-the-intention-of-odr)

Comment: This is an ODR violation. The same class type's definition must have the same sequence of tokens in all translation units, and the same meaning of the tokens

Comment: @M.M What about (2)?

Comment: @jw_ unknown, since I have not tried all possible code in all possible conforming compilers that will ever exist .  That's why we have standards documents

Comment: @jw_: Why bother relying on compiler-specific behavior, when you can just shove the two structs in different namespaces (or unnamed namespaces) and thus be assured that your code work in *all* compilers?